# Creating a hyperlink in the VB can't seem the quotes right

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Creating a hyperlink in the VB which goes to a panel in the aspx page.

code I have so far is:

```
eventlist.Text = eventlist.Text & "<div class='event-side-label'>"
        eventlist.Text = eventlist.Text & "<a href='" & row("event_url") "'" & "target='_blank'" ">" & Site link & "</a>"
        eventlist.Text = eventlist.Text & "</div>"
```

I can't seem to get the single and double quotes right, keep getting an error saying end of statement expected just at the quotes after `row("event_url")`.

URL worked fine until I tried to put the `target'_blank'` in.
Can anyone help out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an & after "& row("event_url") "

Comment: and after [ "target='_blank'" ] (or you can the ">" to the previous statement)

Comment: but personally I would use String.Format as it makes it far more readable

Comment: Thanks Lee! I was concentrating on the quotes and totally forgot to check the & symbols!